# Calculate the Offset of two selected cells

Tags: vba, cell, offset

I require that users populate a UserForm with two cells. (Let's say these are cells "D1" and "F2"). I would like to use this offset between these two cells in other parts of the code (after searching for a keyword). Bear in mind users can choose any two cells on the sheet.

Comment: Calculate the difference in rows and columns between the two by comparing their `.Row` and `.Column`?

Comment: Would you like to obtain the cells rows/columns differences? If yes, do you need also negative values, according to first cell position, or only absolute difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function, please.

It will return the difference between rows and columns. If you need an absolute value, just un-comment the code lines making the difference positive:

```
Private Function cellsOffsetRC(Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range) As Variant
   Dim calOff As Long, rowsOff As Long, arrOff(1) As Variant

   arrOff(0) = Cell2.Row - Cell1.Row
    'If arrOff(0) < 0 Then arrOff(0) = arrOff(0) * (-1)
   arrOff(1) = Cell2.Column - Cell1.Column
    'If arrOff(1) < 0 Then arrOff(1) = arrOff(1) * (-1)

    cellsOffsetRC = arrOff
End Function
```

It can  be checked with a test Sub like this:

```
Sub testCellsOffsetRC()
  Dim arrOff As Variant
  arrOff = cellsOffsetRC(Range("D1"), Range("F2"))
  Debug.Print "Rows Offset: " & arrOff(0),"Columns Offset: " &  arrOff(1)
  Debug.Print Range("D1").Offset(arrOff(0), arrOff(1)).address
End Sub
```

Comment: You could just use `Abs` to return the absolute value btw.

Comment: @ BigBen: Yes. I initially had that in my mind. But I thought it is more didactic to firstly return the relative position and then to be obvious what the code wants doing in case of absolute need... He can directly use `Abs` in case of absolute value need. But, I would think it is less probable, since he mentioned that the offset will be used (in other parts of the code...) after it is determined...

Comment: @Kristian: Isn't that what you need? Even if not, it is at least polite to say something when ask a question and somebody tries an answer...

Comment: @FaneDuru perfect thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for :)